# Does a domain sale share the owner’s contact info?

Tags: domains, whois, domain-transfer, transfer, private-registration

I am selling a domain online and my registrar uses privacy protection which is automatically enabled. Behind the privacy protection, I have myself listed as all 3 contacts, along with my personal email, home address, and phone number.

Will this information be available to the purchaser i.e
when transferring a domain name, do the original contacts go along with it?
Will the buyer otherwise have access to my info?

Answer (score 0):

At the time of transfer, the Domain Sale should not share your contact details.  But if you are worried then you could go and change it just before the sale.

Comment: I can’t because of the 60 day lock…and if it doesn’t, why would I be worried?